# How to access images after being atteched to the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

There are images loaded via ajax request to the side.
The problem is that all these images have different size and just some of them needs to have a special width and height.

I need to change the size after these images have been attached to the dom. I mean after they have been attached to this div.

```
<div id="myID" class="justAClass"></div>
```

How is it possible to access images after they have been attached to the DOM ?

Previously I attempted the following:

```
if($('#myID .justaClassName img').attr('width') > 1000 
   && if($('#myID .justaClassName img').attr('height') <= 3000){
   $('#myID .justaClassName img').css({
      'width'  : '200px',
      'height' : '400px'
   });
}
```

Comment: what's the problem with `$('#myID img')`?

Comment: how are you attaching them to the DOM? You can just give them a class and style it the way you need.

Comment: justaClassName !== justAClass ! naming

Comment: Of course, if you call `attr()` on a collection it only uses the first item. Is that your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can access your images using the following javascript:

```
const images = document.querySelectorAll('#myID img')
```

Answer (score 0):

Three possible solutions follow:

1) Use CSS
2) Select the image directly with jQuery
3) Use a MutationObserver

---

1) First and foremost always try to solve a style problem with CSS. You may be able to set `max-width` and `max-height` properties to constrain your images to their containing parent.

```
#myId img {
    /* try different values here like your original 200 x 400 */
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

2) However, this likely does not meet all your requirements however. You stated a specific condition for image resize, and that is width > 1000 and height <= 3000. This leads me to believe you want images smaller than that to stay their original size while images larger than that get resized to 200 x 400.

If possible, you should modify the code directly by selecting the image correctly with jQuery: `$('#myID img')`.

3) In the event you do not control the code which is changing your page, you can setup a  [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to watch for DOM changes. Whenever the image changes, an observer can determine its size and adjust accordingly.

The solution I propose is useful in such cases where you do not control all the code. It may be that some images are dynamically loaded by a script you cannot edit.

```
var target = document.getElementById('myID');

var config = {
    attributes: false,
    childList: true,
    characterData: false
};

var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    // the first image added to #myID
    var img = mutations[0].addedNodes[0];

    if (img.width > 1000 && img.height <= 3000) {
        img.width = 400;
        img.height = 200;
    }
});

observer.observe(target, config);
```

Putting it all together in a demo:

```js
var doodles = [
    'https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2017/freedom-day-and-enoch-sontonga-5748739204448256-2x.jpg',
    'https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2017/kings-day-2017-5641966854340608.15-2xa.gif',
    'https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2017/childrens-day-2017-mexico-5079016900919296-2x.png'
];

window.onload = function () {
    
    var target = document.getElementById('myID');
    
    var config = {
        attributes: false,
        childList: true,
        characterData: true
    };
    
    var observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
        var img = mutations[0].addedNodes[0];
        if (img.width > 400 && img.height <= 3000) {
            img.width = 400;
            img.height = 200;
        }
    });
    
    observer.observe(target, config);
    
    target.onclick = function () {
        var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * doodles.length);
        target.innerHTML = '<img src="' + doodles[r] + '">';
    };
};
```

```css
#myID {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    border: solid black 3px;
    border-style: dashed;
    padding: 14px;
    margin: 3px;
}

img {
    border: solid black 1px;
}
```

```html
<div id="myID" class="justAClass">Click to Load</div>
```

Comment: Every now and then, the observer seems to fail to pick up the change. Moreover, you should check [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=mutation%20observer) for support across browsers